# Wrong use of !URLFOR inside a controller of aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, static-resources, urlfor

I'm trying to get a .js file inside a zipped file loaded in Salesforce as Static Resource from the controller of an aura component.
When I use:

```
baseUrl: "{!URLFOR($Resource.layer_composer,'js/lib')}",
```

I get  the wrong URL like:

```
https://sit-sit-octoforce.cs86.force.com/businesscustomer/s/%7B!URLFOR($Resource.layer_composer,'js/lib')
```

(js/lib it's the folder I want to and layer_composer the static resource).
Clearly it's wrong, so which is the right way to retrive js/lib inside the layer_composer Static Resources from the aura component controller?

Answer (score 10):

See [$Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm).

To use $Resource in JavaScript, you have to actually call a method. Here's an example from the docs:

```
({
    profileUrl: function(component) {
        var profUrl = $A.get('$Resource.SLDSv2') + '/assets/images/avatar1.jpg';
        alert("Profile URL: " + profUrl);
    }
})
```

When using URLFOR in component markup, you can use it directly, as demonstrated here:

```
<aura:component>
  <ltng:require 
    styles="{!$Resource.SLDSv2 + '/assets/styles/lightning-design-system-ltng.css'}"
    scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

If you need more than one resource, use `join`:

```
scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}"
```

URLFOR is an artifact of Visualforce, and is not needed in Lightning at all.

Comment: with "$A.get('$Resource')" is taking a well formed URL but it's still the wrong URL. My Static Resource is in: "https://octoforce--sit.cs86.my.salesforce.com/", while the alert give me "https://sit-sit-octoforce.cs86.force.com/businesscustomer/asset" where "businesscustom" is the community name. Is it means that I have to put the layer_comper zip file inside the community asset?

Comment: @L.benedettini I don't have a lot of experience with community (about 5 minutes worth), but yes, it does appear that you need to re-upload the images as assets in the community asset resources for them to be available. Can you try that and let me know if it works?